# User getting "AccessDenied" on IE 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0, internet-explorer-10, access-denied

I have several users complaining about not being able to use my website using an IE 10 explorer but they can using IE 9 and Chrome. Their problem is that they are able to login but when clicking any other tab they are getting an `AccessDenied` error which is only possible if the user has not logged in or we are unable to check the user information stored in a cookie which is available after successful login.  I wonder if using the fix described at [Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) will solve my problem.

I did observe the `ie.browser`, `firefox.browser` files on my production server are not as they should be as described in the above article.  What is really confusing is that I am able to login on IE 10 and use the website without any issues and I am not able to reproduce the issue?

Please advice on what could be the real problem and if I should apply the fix without it breaking anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved. Yes, this is a problem with the browser IE 10 because it works fine for all users when they turn their "Compatibility View" ON. I was not able to reproduce the issue because their comaptiblity view settings were enabled on my browser because of my company group policy settings on my browser.
- One way to resolve this is to apply the hotfix or use the method to update the .browser files.
- Else you can install .NET 4.5 which I would have to eventually do that also updates the .browser files. Since your application is targetting .NET 4.0 it still works as expected except you won't have any issues. This also fixes the other CSS issues with the website.
Thanks rocky for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it the JavaScript Access Denied message? It can occur e.g. when you try to access window object that you have reference on but it no longer exists. I have seen this problem only on sites with multiple frames/iframes/popup windows (which were trying to communicate with each other). It is almost irreproducible when debugging (using F12 -> Dev. tools). Try to wrap your code to try-catch and put

```
debugger;
```

into the catch. The debugger will be invoked and you will be able to examine the problem. The JavaScript debugging have to be turned off before you try this!

Or you can force your visitors to add your site to trusted zones as described in this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908356).

Comment: I just discovered that once you turn on the "Compatibility View" setting for my website on IE 10, I no longer get the "Access Denied" error. Else even I get the "Access Denied" error when I log in as a website admin. Any reason or alternative without having my users to do this setting on their end?

Comment: I forgot to mention that compatibility view settings also influence the behavior. And as I said, you have to debug the issue to find out what is causing the error (using my instructions above). When you find the source of the problem you will be able to fix it or at least wrap it into try-catch. There is no general recipe how to solve this problem. :)

Comment: I can help you if you find the piece of code that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Changing "Compatibility View" worked for me when I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setTimeout(function() {..},1000);
```

Sometimes in IE8 the document.domain isn't set fast enough, I've had to call iframe functions after a timeout before to get it to work - or I get the same issues.